# ORA-00904 Invalid Identifier with JPA EclipseLink 2.1

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jpa

I’m trying to create a basic CRUD database in JPA but I’m getting stuck on the ‘read’ part. I’ve got a client table created with a couple of fields that stores information on clients, but for some reason, a basic JPA TypedQuery can’t seem to query it without getting hit with an ‘invalid identifier’. I’ve got the creation code here, and nothing seems out of place.

```
create table Client (
cid NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
fname VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,
lname VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR2(255),
phone VARCHAR2(255),
address VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
age number NOT NULL
);
```

And the code here that I’m using to query the class, it’s just a basic `TypedQuery`.

```
TypedQuery<Client> query = em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Client a", Client.class);
    List<Client> results = query.getResultList();
```

And the output (thrown into a snippet for formatting):

```js
[EL Info]: 2017-11-29 14:56:23.809--ServerSession(1905114489)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd
[EL Info]: connection: 2017-11-29 14:56:24.091--ServerSession(1905114489)--file:////COMPHOME/homedir$/X00136103/Documents/CA2BANKACCOUNT/build/classes/_CA2BANKACCOUNTPU login successful
[EL Warning]: 2017-11-29 14:56:24.356--UnitOfWork(48522228)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "PHONE": invalid identifier

Error Code: 904
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Call: SELECT CID, address, age, email, firstname, lastname, phone FROM Client
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Client sql="SELECT CID, address, age, email, firstname, lastname, phone FROM Client")
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "PHONE": invalid identifier

Error Code: 904
Call: SELECT CID, address, age, email, firstname, lastname, phone FROM Client
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Client sql="SELECT CID, address, age, email, firstname, lastname, phone FROM Client")
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getDetailedException(QueryImpl.java:378)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:260)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:469)
 at model.dbOperations.viewClients(dbOperations.java:21)
 at test.Test.main(Test.java:18)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "PHONE": invalid identifier

Error Code: 904
Call: SELECT CID, address, age, email, firstname, lastname, phone FROM Client
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Client sql="SELECT CID, address, age, email, firstname, lastname, phone FROM Client")
 at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:340)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:682)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:558)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2002)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:570)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:299)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:694)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRowsFromTable(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2738)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2691)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadAllQuery.java:495)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1168)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:899)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1127)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:403)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1215)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2896)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1804)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1786)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1751)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:258)
 ... 3 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "PHONE": invalid identifier

 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1017)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:655)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:249)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:566)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:215)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:58)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:776)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:897)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1034)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3820)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3867)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1502)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:1007)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:642)
 ... 23 more
```

No matter what I try to do, it seems like the table can’t find ‘phone’. It’s constantly invalid and I’m not sure why.

Comment: ORA-00904 indicates it is the database that is tossing up the error, not EclipseLink. That error has been asked about several other times before, a quick google shows you more with possible causes. Given that there is a blatant typo in the create SQL you provided I am going to assume it is not the exact SQL executed.

Comment: Do a describe on the table and make sure the `PHONE` column exists and is spelled correctly?

Comment: @Gimby Yeah, I somehow got rid of a bracket when I was pasting. Edited now. I'm just about 100% sure it's EclipseLink giving the error as I've tested all of the SQL and created all of the tables from the SQL provided. They all work perfectly, but once I try to query the same table using a TypedQuery object, the error is thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote:

> I've got the creation code here, and nothing seems out of place.

But when I compare your creation script:

```
create table Client (
    cid NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    fname VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,
    lname VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR2(255),
    phone VARCHAR2(255),
    address VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   age number NOT NULL
);
```

and the `SELECT` statement from the stacktrace:

```
Error Code: 904
Call: SELECT CID, address, age, email, firstname, lastname, phone FROM Client
```

they are not identical. In the stacktrace, that is what EclipseLink is generating, you have `firstname` and `lastname` columns where as these column names are not in your `CREATE TABLE` statement. I think you have to edit your entity or correct your DDL.

**Update:**

I don't know why it is not working for you. I have just done the following on Oracle 11 and EclipseLink, and everything is works:

- The entity:

  ```
  @Entity
  public class Client {

      @Id
      @GeneratedValue
      private int cid;

      @Column(name = "firstname", nullable = false)
      private String fname;

      @Column(name = "lastname", nullable = false)
      private String lname;

      private String email;
      private String phone;

      @Column(name = "address", nullable = false)
      private String address;
      int age;

      public int getCid() {
          return cid;
      }

      public void setCid(int cid) {
          this.cid = cid;
      }

      // rest of getters / setters
  }
  ```
- EclipseLink generated SQL:

  ```
  CREATE TABLE CLIENT (
      CID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL, 
      address VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL, 
      AGE NUMBER(10) NULL, 
      EMAIL VARCHAR2(255) NULL, 
      firstname VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL, 
      lastname VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL, 
      PHONE VARCHAR2(255) NULL, PRIMARY KEY (CID))
  ```
- Screenshot from the DB
  [image]

Comment: I've been playing around with this for a while and the select statement there is only receiving its variables from the column names that I've defined for all of the client variables. This might describe it better https://i.imgur.com/YhUYTTV.png. I've tried executing the query without naming the columns like this and naming them the same as the fields the correspond to in the database. It doesn't seem to change anything. Alternatively I removed 'phone' altogether and it told me that the 'lname' column was invalid, so it seems like there's something else wrong beyond just an invalid identifier.

Comment: Take a look at the updated answer. It might help you to find where you're making mistake.

Comment: After going through the whole project creation process and setting everything up again and using your code I suddenly realized what was wrong. The persistence unit was configured the wrong way and was querying a different database schema, and that other schema had a client table in it. Problem's solved now and the query seems to be working perfectly.